# How to get Content type and Content Dipostion in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get content type and content disposition of a url using java-script?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some context.

Comment: If I am correct, you could use ajax to get your url, but use HEAD method, that will return to you only request headers. It's light and if server supports it, you will have your info.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't an API to give you the HTTP response headers for your initial page request.

**[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)**

Although you could make a new request and read those:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```